# Opening a Console from a form vb

Tags: vb.net

I have searched around for a way to activate a console application from a windows form however I have only been able to find tutorials to activate a Form from a console.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

ToffeeMax

Comment: Are you saying that you want to display a console window from within the same WinForm application?  Or are you saying that you want to launch the console application as a separate process?

Comment: Launch Another Console Application.

Comment: Have you tried [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have tried that, However that takes a specific file location. Would it be possible to not hard code the location?

Comment: Yes, you can pass it any value.  If you do not specify a path, the OS will find it via the normal search paths.  But you can use other methods to get the correct path.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :D